# android draw an image on canvas after traslate

Tags: android, xml, animation, canvas, draw

I want to draw an image to a canvas with the same coordinate everytime.but i cant achive that.this is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


            // Draw the thumb nail
            canvas.translate(mTranslateX - mThumbXPos, mTranslateY - mThumbYPos);
            mThumb.draw(canvas);

            canvas.save();

            if (firstTime)
            {

                mFirstTranslateY= mTranslateX;
                mFirstThumbXPos= mThumbXPos;
                mFirstTranslateY= mTranslateY;
                mFirstThumbYPos= mThumbYPos;
                firstTime = false;

                }else {

                canvas.restore();
                canvas.translate(mFirstTranslateX - mFirstThumbXPos, mFirstTranslateY - mFirstThumbYPos);
                    mThumbPresent.draw(canvas);
                }
            }
```

}

I just make negative translate every time and then make a translate to the first position of the thumbnail.I use seek arc library.i have the thumbnail for change degree and what I want is to draw these two circles(21 and 32) on the image below.

[image i want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5wHM.png)

Comment: use `Canvas#save` / `Canvas#restore`

Comment: @pskink you mean after I use  mThumb.draw(canvas); i use canvas.save() and after that use Canvas#restore and then mThumbPresent.draw(canvas);  ???

Comment: did you read `save()` documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @pskink the save method holds the current situation of canvas am I right?

Comment: @pskink you mean this ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#save()

Comment: @pskink i've edited my code is this what you mean?

Comment: @pskink i can understand that but i want to mThumb draw base on translate and after that, i save the first translate of it to draw mThumbPresent and this would not change every time on draw called.i think i can't get what you are supposed to say to me.

Comment: @pskink when I restore canvas the coordinate that changes because of translate were come back to 0,0 and then i can translate agin and draw my second drawable